# Android App is not running. Emulator says it keeps shutting down

Tags: java, android

I have some code that should be very simple to run on an Android App. I have a textView that I am trying to print the day of the year out of 365 of 366. However, even though the code is simple, it is not running but there is also no error message.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(new Date()); // Give your own date
    int dayOfYear = (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText(dayOfYear);
}
```

I have all the necessary import statements to not get any errors in the Android Studio. It just doesn't work when I run it.
It should just set the text to whatever day of the year today is. It should be 44 today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
tv1.setText(dayOfYear);
```

must be changed to:

```
tv1.setText("" + dayOfYear);
```

or

```
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfYear));
```

because `setText()` needs a string as an argument. 
When you pass an integer it is considered as a resource id.